# Jquery TE placeholder not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-textext

Beforehand, I want add that I think this is a bug.
I'm trying to add a placeholder to [jqueryte](http://jqueryte.com/) like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/euhSX/).

But it simply doesnt show the placeholder by using `$().jqte({placeholder: "myplaceholder"});`

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a jqte user or expert, but I noticed that the css has

```
.jqte_placeholder {
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}
```

if you override that with:

```
.jqte_placeholder {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/euhSX/1/

it works in Safari and Chrome (I didn't try it in anything else)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Are you saying it doesn't resize the editor?  It shows up as placeholder text for me, but I can't see all of it.  Why would you want massive amounts of placeholder text?  The moment the user types anything it's gone, so it's better suited for simple instructions.

Comment: I know. But I do wanna put this amount of information there. What can we do?

Comment: @PatrickBassut - what would you like to happen?  Do you want the control to scroll or maybe resize to fit? Do really want it to be placeholder text or would actual text be better? I don't understand your use case.

Comment: I dont know if using a placeholder is the best choice here. But I wanna explain whats the meaning of some field inside the textarea. And when the user clicks and types it should be gone(as you said). And I have some relatively big texts here to explain that.